# Error installing mysql2 gem on Ruby 1.9.2

Tags: mysql, ruby, rubygems, mysql2

I am currently trying to install the mysql2 gem for a Ruby on Rails application. I am using Ruby 1.9.2. Here is the error:

```
todd-andrewss-macbook:shiftly toddOld$ gem install mysql2
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql2:
 ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/Users/toddOld/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes
checking for mysql.h... yes
checking for errmsg.h... yes
checking for mysqld_error.h... yes
creating Makefile

make
gcc -I. -I/Users/toddOld/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/include/ruby-1.9.1/i386-darwin9.8.0 -I/Users/toddOld/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/Users/toddOld/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -DHAVE_RB_THREAD_BLOCKING_REGION -DHAVE_MYSQL_H -DHAVE_ERRMSG_H -DHAVE_MYSQLD_ERROR_H -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE   -I/usr/local/mysql/include  -g -Os -arch x86_64 -fno-common   -D_P1003_1B_VISIBLE -DSIGNAL_WITH_VIO_CLOSE -DSIGNALS_DONT_BREAK_READ -DIGNORE_SIGHUP_SIGQUIT  -DDONT_DECLARE_CXA_PURE_VIRTUAL -fno-common -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wno-long-long  -fno-common -pipe -Wall -funroll-loops  -o client.o -c client.c
In file included from /Users/toddOld/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby.h:32,
                 from ./mysql2_ext.h:4,
                 from client.c:1:
/Users/toddOld/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h:108: error: size of array ‘ruby_check_sizeof_long’ is negative
/Users/toddOld/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h:112: error: size of array ‘ruby_check_sizeof_voidp’ is negative
In file included from /Users/toddOld/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/intern.h:29,
                 from /Users/toddOld/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h:1327,
                 from /Users/toddOld/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby.h:32,
                 from ./mysql2_ext.h:4,
                 from client.c:1:
/Users/toddOld/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/st.h:69: error: size of array ‘st_check_for_sizeof_st_index_t’ is negative
client.c: In function ‘rb_raise_mysql2_error’:
client.c:79: warning: comparison is always true due to limited range of data type
client.c:79: warning: comparison is always true due to limited range of data type
client.c: In function ‘rb_mysql_client_socket’:
client.c:412: warning: comparison is always true due to limited range of data type
client.c:412: warning: comparison is always true due to limited range of data type
client.c: In function ‘init_mysql2_client’:
client.c:556: warning: comparison is always true due to limited range of data type
client.c:556: warning: comparison is always true due to limited range of data type
client.c:561: warning: comparison is always true due to limited range of data type
client.c:561: warning: comparison is always true due to limited range of data type
client.c:566: warning: comparison is always true due to limited range of data type
client.c:566: warning: comparison is always true due to limited range of data type
client.c:571: warning: comparison is always true due to limited range of data type
client.c:571: warning: comparison is always true due to limited range of data type
client.c:576: warning: comparison is always true due to limited range of data type
client.c:576: warning: comparison is always true due to limited range of data type
client.c:580: warning: comparison is always true due to limited range of data type
client.c:580: warning: comparison is always true due to limited range of data type
client.c:584: warning: comparison is always true due to limited range of data type
client.c:584: warning: comparison is always true due to limited range of data type
client.c:589: warning: comparison is always true due to limited range of data type
client.c:589: warning: comparison is always true due to limited range of data type
client.c:594: warning: comparison is always true due to limited range of data type
client.c:594: warning: comparison is always true due to limited range of data type
client.c:599: warning: comparison is always true due to limited range of data type
client.c:599: warning: comparison is always true due to limited range of data type
client.c:604: warning: comparison is always true due to limited range of data type
client.c:604: warning: comparison is always true due to limited range of data type
client.c:608: warning: comparison is always true due to limited range of data type
client.c:608: warning: comparison is always true due to limited range of data type
client.c:613: warning: comparison is always true due to limited range of data type
client.c:613: warning: comparison is always true due to limited range of data type
client.c:618: warning: comparison is always true due to limited range of data type
client.c:618: warning: comparison is always true due to limited range of data type
client.c:622: warning: comparison is always true due to limited range of data type
client.c:622: warning: comparison is always true due to limited range of data type
client.c:627: warning: comparison is always true due to limited range of data type
client.c:627: warning: comparison is always true due to limited range of data type
client.c:632: warning: implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value
client.c:632: warning: comparison is always true due to limited range of data type
client.c:632: warning: comparison is always true due to limited range of data type
client.c:642: warning: implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value
client.c:642: warning: comparison is always true due to limited range of data type
client.c:642: warning: comparison is always true due to limited range of data type
client.c:647: warning: implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value
client.c:647: warning: comparison is always true due to limited range of data type
client.c:647: warning: comparison is always true due to limited range of data type
client.c:652: warning: implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value
client.c:652: warning: comparison is always true due to limited range of data type
client.c:652: warning: comparison is always true due to limited range of data type
client.c:657: warning: implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value
client.c:657: warning: comparison is always true due to limited range of data type
client.c:657: warning: comparison is always true due to limited range of data type
make: *** [client.o] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/toddOld/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/mysql2-0.2.6 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/toddO

ld/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/mysql2-0.2.6/ext/mysql2/gem_make.out
```

I tried installing with a number of different MySQL versions, including 5.5.6.rc, 5.1.14 and 5.1.49. I am running Mac OS X 10.5.8 with the XCode tools installed.  I confirmed that MySQL works from the command line and connects correctly.

Comment: try installing an older version of the gem.

Answer (score 1):

Check your Ruby version. If it's 64-bit then your MySQL needs to be 64-bit and vice versa.

Also install with `archflags` according to the installation and add `--no-ri` and `--no-rdoc`.

Comment: It would seem your correct. I ended up compiling mysql from source and it worked fine.